# I got _this._driver.validateStyleProperty is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material with Angular v6. When I used it in my HTML file. I got an error like this:

```
ERROR TypeError: _this._driver.validateStyleProperty is not a function
```

Excerpt from my Angular Material module:

```ts
MatFormFieldModule,
MatInputModule,
MatSelectModule
```

HTML usage:

```html
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-select placeholder="Select item">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let x of data" [value]="x.value">
                {{x.viewValue}}
         </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

After so many googling and RND, I have tried changing the version of Angular Animations and Angular Material. But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Which version of `angular-material` are you using?

Comment: I used  `@angular/material": "^6.3.2" ` @ Amit Chigadani

Comment: Could you specify what version of Angular Animations you're using, as well as your _full_ Angular Material module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating angular material will fix your problem

```
ng update @angular/cli
ng update @angular/core
ng update @angular/material
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay,. 
I have also seen this steps. But I have a doubt that it might me affect to other modules or projects. Am I right or wrong ?

Comment: it will not affect try this